# first value as a default in Drop Down List

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

i need to default the first value of the drop down list and pass it to my controller.

Below is my code. Please suggest what wrong i am doing.

Component:

```
 <aura:attribute name="pltfrmGrpOptions" type="string[]"/>
    <div class="container">
        <form aura:id="frm1">
            <fieldset>
            <ui:inputSelect aura:id="ProductPlatform" class="form-control" label="Product Platform" change="{!c.onSelectChange}" required="true"> 
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.pltfrmGrpOptions}" var="level">
                    <ui:inputSelectOption value="{!level}" label="{!level}" text="{!level}" />
                </aura:iteration>
            </ui:inputSelect> 
            ....
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

i need to mark the first value in the drop down list as the default value. Please suggest. 
Currently, if i do not select any value from drop down, my controller receives an **undefined** value.

Comment: can u share ur controller code as well.. in which controller action method you are getting undefined ? is it in onSelectChange event or some other place ?

Comment: In your Level list don't pass any blank or none option value . Then first value will be default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tushar said you shouldn't pass any blank option value in the controller. Still if you want to set a dropdown value as default value in your Lightning component you can do this as below. `<aura:iteration` has a attribute indexVar which provides the position of the dropdown starting from 0. You can use this with `<aura:if` to set `value="true"` for any dropdown value to make it default. In your case it will be 0 as the first one is default. Hope this helps.

**Example**

```
<aura:iteration items="1,2,3,4,5" var="item" indexVar="index">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!index ==0}" >
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!item}" value="true"/>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!item}"/>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:iteration>
```

**Your code will be updated as below**

```
 <aura:attribute name="pltfrmGrpOptions" type="string[]"/>
    <div class="container">
        <form aura:id="frm1">
            <fieldset>
            <ui:inputSelect aura:id="ProductPlatform" class="form-control" label="Product Platform" change="{!c.onSelectChange}" required="true"> 
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.pltfrmGrpOptions}" var="level" indexVar="index">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!index ==0}" >
                    <ui:inputSelectOption value="{!level}" label="{!level}" text="{!level}" value="true" />
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <ui:inputSelectOption value="{!level}" label="{!level}" text="{!level}" />
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
                </aura:iteration>
            </ui:inputSelect> 
            ....
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Saroj, thanks for your reply.  After making this changes also my controller is taking the undefined value. When i submit the form, i need to pass this input selected value to my controller. So i used `var propltform = component.find("ProductPlatform").get("v.value");`' ... this still takes the value undefined.

Comment: only when i select some value from drop down list this value is getting set in controller.

Comment: i noticed, when i use `items="1,2,3,4"` it , takes 1 as default , but when i add `items={!v.pltfrmGrpOptions}` , it is returning undefined and not the 0 index value.  `pltfrmGrpOptions` returns result based on sql query in apex class controller.

Comment: please refer the [link] (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99922/returns-undefined-when-passing-the-first-default-value-of-drop-down-list-to-co) for this query @Saroj Bera

Answer (score 0):

This approach should work, but default option is last one in the array. Seems "selected: true" does not work when do it dynamically :(

------- in my component --------

```
<ui:inputSelect label="" class="dynamic" aura:id="itemId" />
```

-------- js controller ---------

```
var pickOptArr = [1, 2, 3];
var picklistOptionsArray = new Array();

/* also tried add first element like this (then pickOptArr = [2, 3]): 
picklistOptionsArray.push({ "class": "optionClass", label: "", value: 1, selected: "true" });
*/

for(var i = 0; i < pickOptArr.length; i++){
               if(pickOptArr[i] !== defaultOpt){
                    picklistOptionsArray.push({ "class": "optionClass", label: "", value: pickOptArr[i], selected: "false" });
               }
           }

picklistOptionsArray[0].selected = true;

component.find(itemId).set("v.options", picklistOptionsArray);
```

----- result -----

default option is always 3 - the last one I placed into picklistOptionsArray

Comment: ------- in my component --------                                                                    <ui:inputSelect label="" class="dynamic" aura:id="itemId"/>     defaultOpt = 1